# How to save instance of recyclerView after a drag and drop

Tags: android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, android-savedstate, sectionedrecyclerviewadapter

I want to save the state of recyclerView after the drag and drop is there any way so far I have tried everything like sharedPreference,savedInstance etc.. is there any way to solve this issue. What I want is when I close the app and reopen it the recyclerView shall remain the same way as it was during drag and drop.